# Designing xml layouts for different screen: Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-screen

I am working on a small app, with 3 buttons on left corner(Vertically) and a edit box which covers rest of the screen.

I want to run this app to be able to work on all screen resolutions.
So I have used Relative layout, linear layout and Android:weight for buttons, which equally share the size of the buttons and works fine.

My Question is am I doing it wrong?

Should we design different layouts for different screens or using same layout out but adding properties like weight and padding is fine??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So, you want a responsive layout for your android app.

**Pointing to your question :**

> [+1] layout -> Relative / Linear (in addition to the relative layout)
>
> property (Buttons) -> Android:weight

is the right thing you are doing for your app.

**Alternative:**

But if you want a more [responsive design](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/responsivedesign/) then you could follow responsive design techniques by using html5 & css3 media queries etc. . And, could opt for a fluid layout also. By doing this the advantages you will have are:

> - Won't have a native UI only for **android** but the same could be used for other platforms (**iOS,blackberry** etc.) if you require.
> - The design would be more seamless with the native browser and the widgets won't get obsolete ever in the newer versions of your android
>     platform also and changes once done would be reflected over the other
>     platforms too.

**More info: MUST READ IF YOU WANT CLEAR UNDERSTANDING OF HOW TO DESIGN FOR ANDROID**

http://developer.android.com/design/style/devices-displays.html
http://developer.android.com/design/style/metrics-grids.html#48dp-rhythm

Answer (score 2):

you can see this [`Supporting Multiple Screens`](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) and also [`Designing for Multiple Screens`](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html)

Comment: and you should see [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Answer (score 1):

To support different screen size you have to implement different layout.
Under res directory you should create these directory:

layout
layout-small
layout-large
layout-xlarge

In each directory you implement your layout. be aware to call all the layouts with the same name.
If you want to support the landscape mode too you have to add:

layout-small-land
layout-large-land
layout-land

When, in Eclipse, you open the layout select the tab called 'Graphical Layout' , you will see how your layout will be displayed. Change the screen size using the options in the upper left side and you can check how it will be displayed in different screen size.
If something is wrong you can open the xml using and correct it.
I've created a small tutorial here [Multiple screen support](https://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/07/how-to-support-multiple-screen-in.html)

Hope this help you